# Is efficiency greater than unity valid?

Tags: performance, openmp

I'm running a C code with OpenMP directive, at Intel i5-2410M (dual core with Hyper-threading).

Since by using `#pragma omp parallel for simd`,
the speedup achieved could be about x1000, as such:

`#pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c) private(i,j,k) {
    #pragma omp for simd collapse (3)
    for (i=0; i<5000; i++){
      for (j=0; j<5000; j++){
        for (k=0; k<5000; k=k+1){
            a[i][j]=(a[i][j])+((b[i][k])*(c[k][j]));
         } } }
   }`

And, the formula for calculating efficiency = Speedup / no. of processors

Thus, efficiency = 1000 / 1 = 1000. Is it valid?

I've never seen efficiency which is greater than 1. It really makes me confused as I don't know whether efficiency > 1 is a valid figure or not.

Hope you can clear up my doubt.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you measure that speedup ?  Show us your code and your run-times.  Safe to say that a speedup of 1000 on that processor, just going from serial execution to parallel execution, is unlikely.

Comment: You should exclude the speedup of simd when measuring efficiency of parallelization. You measure speedup as the ratio between multi-threaded run time vs. single-threaded run time with all other aspects unchanged.

Comment: So, the formula was meant for measuring parallel efficiency only. Is there a way to calculate "SIMD efficiency"?

Comment: There are real cases where you can see an efficiency greater than 1 e.g. from a super linearly speedup due to the cache. In your case it's impossible to say without showing your code and what compile options you used (also the compiler and OS could be interesting). OpenMP has less strict rules for example with floating point arithmetic so in some cases I could imagine that using OpenMP let's the compiler optimize a loop to a single iteration because of looser rules. As I said it's impossible to know without code.

Comment: Hi, I'd edited the question. Just want to be clear, the formula of efficiency = Speedup / no. of processors    is meant for calculating parallel efficiency only. If SIMD is involved, then it is not valid anymore. Is it true?